# Constructions "be but one" vs "but + pronoun"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, differences, word-usage

I've seen these constructions several times and I've found the following definitions **(correct or confirm the definitions)**:

```
but + noun/pronoun = except
```

*She gave the presents to everyone **but me** =

She gave the presents to everyone **except** me*

```
be but one = the only one/the only
```

*I am **but one** who received the present = 

I am **the only one** who received the present*

In addition, can I use **be but one** without **be**? 
*She gave **but one** present I desired to me = 

She gave **the only one** present I desired to me*

and **but + noun** and not only with **pronoun**
*She sold all the flowers **but the yellow one** =

She sold all the flowers **except the yellow ones***

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Whether the usages in the examples correct or not

Comment: For one, "I am but one who received the present" does not mean "I am the only one who received the present." In fact, it is almost the opposite, meaning "I am one [of many] who received the present."

Comment: Your last example is the same as the first, where _but = except_. As @StardustGogeta says, _I am but one_ means _I am just one of many_.  Your other example doesn't work; I would say _the one present I desired_.

Comment: what means "doesn't work"? Is "to give but one present" an invalid sentence? Or does it mean that it is impossible to understand without context?